# How can I get the first part of a string in PHP?

Tags: php

I've this string in PHP:

```
App\Classes\Frontend\Builder
```

I'm already getting the last word which is my class:

```
$class_name = 'App\Classes\Frontend\Builder';
$pos        = strrpos( $class_name, '\\' );
$class      = strtolower( substr( $class_name, $pos + 1 ) ); //Returns Builder
```

But how can I get now everything before `App\Classes\Frontend` without the last `\`?

Comment: `substr( $class_name,0,  $pos )`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take `substr` from position 0 to `$pos`:

```
$class_name = 'App\Classes\Frontend\Builder';
$pos        = strrpos( $class_name, '\\' );
$class      = strtolower( substr( $class_name, 0, $pos ) ); //Returns app\classes\frontend
```

Answer (score 0):

Use explode() to create an array and get class name extracting it from the last element (array_pop) and glue everything again to get the namespace

```
$class_name = 'App\Classes\Frontend\Builder';
$parts      = explode("\\", $class_name);
$class      = array_pop($parts); // Returns Builder
$name_space = implode("\\", $parts); // Returns App\Classes\Frontend
```

Comment: `array_pop` I presume.